# Why does Firebird 2.5.8 return NONE on SELECT CURRENT_ROLE?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, flamerobin

Following on from my question here
[How to REVOKE ROLE GRANTED BY another user on Firebird 2.5.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503859/how-to-revoke-role-granted-by-another-user-on-firebird-2-5-8)

and @Arioch's helpful suggestion to query what ROLE is actually connected prior to the command.

```
SELECT CURRENT_ROLE FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Now despite my connection string explicitly using "ROLE=RDB$ADMIN", checking in gsec that the given user has admin option, when I run the command the result is NONE. This was using the Firebird ADO.NET FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient interface v6.6.

So I performed a similar check by using FlameRobin, logging in with the same user and the RDB$ADMIN ROLE specified, and the result is the same:

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong as to why this is not returning 'RDB$ADMIN'?

Answer (score 3):

As user rights are granted in a specific database, the user must be RDB$ADMIN in that specific database and must specify the role on connect. That a user has the admin role in GSEC only means that a user has the admin role in the security database. That doesn't mean they have the admin role in a specific database.

The fact `CURRENT_ROLE` returns `NONE` means that the user either didn't specify a role, or hasn't been granted the RDB$ADMIN role in the current database.

To quote from the [Firebird Language Reference, User Authentication, RDB$ADMIN Role](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-rdbadmin):

> The internally-created role RDB$ADMIN is present in every database.
> Assigning the RDB$ADMIN role to a regular user in a database grants
> that user the privileges of the SYSDBA, in the current database only.
>
> The elevated privileges take effect when the user is logged in to that
> regular database under the RDB$ADMIN role and give full control over
> all objects in the database.
>
> Being granted the RDB$ADMIN role in the security database confers the
> authority to create, edit and delete user accounts.

and

> To manage user accounts through SQL, the grantee must specify the
> RDB$ADMIN role when connecting. No user can connect to the security
> database, so the solution is that the user connects to a regular
> database where he also has RDB$ADMIN rights, supplying the RDB$ADMIN
> role in his login parameters. From there, he can submit any SQL user
> management command.
>
> The SQL route for the user is blocked for any database in which he has
> not been the granted the RDB$ADMIN role.

The `GRANT ADMIN ROLE` clause applies only to the security database (specifically for the `CREATE/ALTER/DROP USER` SQL user management statements), and only if the user connects through a normal database where they also have the RDB$ADMIN role specifying that role on connect.

To grant a user administrator privileges in a specific database, they need to have been granted that role - in that specific database - using:

```
GRANT [ROLE] RDB$ADMIN TO username
```

And they need to specify the role on connect.

Comment: One more thing is `gsec` functionality seems to be reduced in FB3 ( can not select non-default security provider ) and will be totally disabled one day later. Since topic starter was asking about FB3, he better prepare to get rid of `gsec` in his workflow

Comment: @Arioch'The gsec is deprecated, as mentioned in the Firebird 3 release notes. On the other hand, given how Firebird handles other deprecated things (eg dialect 1), who knows how long it will take for it to be really gone.

Comment: Perhaps not that long... Though i'd prefer they rather extended it. Another comparison point can be ODS 9.x till 11.x in FB3